# Two threads giving different output from same function RT Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, queue, pthreads

i have a 2 threads and a function, im calling the same function "no_elements()" from  two threads
the function is

```
int front = -1, rear = -1;
int no_elements()
{

int q_size = 0;

if (front == 0)
{
    
    q_size = rear + 1;

    return q_size;
}
else if (front != 0 && rear != 0)
{
    
    q_size = (rear - front) + 1;
    return q_size;
}
else if (rear == 0 && front != 0)
{
    
    q_size = (SIZE - front)+1;
    return q_size;
}
else if (rear == -1 || front == -1 )
    {
        q_size = 0;
        printf("empty---- ---------------------------------------------------------------------");
        return q_size;
    }

}
```

and the two threads call the same function

```
iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, producer,(void*) message1);
iret2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, consumer,(void*) message2);
```

Producer and consumer functions are

```
void *producer(void *ptr) // enque function
{
char *message;
printf("%s \n", message);
enQueue(data);
printf("No of elements%d\n",no_elements());
}
```

second function is

```
void *consumer(void *ptr) // enque function
{
char *message;
printf("%s \n", message);
printf("No of elements%d\n",no_elements());
}
```

and enqueue function is

```
void enQueue(double *element)
{

 if (isFull())
 printf("\n Queue is full!! \n");
 else
 {

     int i=0;
    if (front == -1)
{
    front = 0;
}
rear = (rear + 1) % SIZE;

memcpy(items[rear].value, element, sizeof (items[rear].value)); // better: sizeof struct

printf("front is  %d--",front);
printf("rear is  %d\n",rear);


 }
}
```

but the first thread gives correct result and second one gives the initialized value of front and rear.

here front and rear are global variables, they are manipulated in first thread by enqueue function, then i call the function no_elements() which returns a value which is correct.

but at the same time the second thread returns the initialized values of front and rear

what can be wrong?

can this be done?

```
   void enQueue(double *element)
   {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

   if (isFull())
    printf("\n Queue is full!! \n");
    else
   {

   int i=0;
   if (front == -1)
   {
  front = 0;
  }
  rear = (rear + 1) % SIZE;

 memcpy(items[rear].value, element, sizeof (items[rear].value)); // better: 
 sizeof struct

printf("front is  %d--",front);
printf("rear is  %d\n",rear);


 }
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

Comment: `char *message; printf("%s \n", message);` invokes *undefined behavior* by using indeterminate value of uninitialized variable. Is this your real executing code?

Comment: yes its executing well

Comment: Would `no_elements` ever output "empty"? You have already checked all possibilities (unless the other thread is altering `front` and `rear`).

Comment: no_elements no it wont give empty, its my mistake
but my problem is that calling no_elements from 2 threads gives 2 results

Comment: Why are there two versions of the `enQueue` function in your question?

Comment: one is with  pthread_mutex and the other without i dono which one would be appropriate

Comment: @RahulKP See my answer. You must not access an object in one thread while another thread is, or might be, modifying that same object. (Except for operations where this is specifically defined. It isn't for things like `front` and `rear`.)

Comment: im not modifying a variable from two threads, im modifying from consumer thread and reading from producer thread

Comment: @RahulKP Read what I wrote *very* carefully. Reading is an access.

Answer (score 1):

Calling your `no_elements()` function and / or your `enqueue()` function from multiple threads that are concurrently alive produces several data races, therefore the behavior of your program is undefined.  The data races arise from those functions accessing shared variables `front`, `rear`, and `items` (at least) without any kind of synchronization, given that some of the accesses are writes.  You must protect shared variables against concurrent access, typically by creating a mutex that each thread must successfully lock before accessing those variables.  Threads must also be sure to unlock the mutex at some point after access in order to afford other threads the opportunity to lock it.

Comment: i have edited my question can u check, i dono how to add code in the comment

Comment: @RahulKP, that modification to your `enqueue()` function is the kind of thing I was describing.  It is not a complete fix by itself, however, even if we assume that `lock` is a poperly initialized mutex, because the `no_elements()` function is involved in the data races too.

Answer (score 1):

The results of accessing an object while another thread is, or might be, accessing it are undefined. You have this problem with both `front` and `read`. So the results of your program are undefined and may be totally unpredictable.

It is the responsibility of the programmer to ensure that threads do not access the same object at the same time. There are lots of tools for this purpose and the first version of `enQueue` uses none of them.

Comment: can you give and example implementation?

Comment: @RahulKP You added one to your question -- using a mutex to ensure that only one thread at a time accesses the shared objects.

Answer (score 0):

When you call pthread_create, what **actually** executes next is indeterminate. From the [pthread_create](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) man page:

> Unless real-time scheduling policies
> are being employed, after a call to pthread_create(), it is
> indeterminate which thread—the caller or the new thread—will next
> execute.

If you extend this to your scenario, where you are creating two threads, it's even more indeterminate what the order of execution is. In other words, you have no way of knowing whether *producer* or *consumer* will start executing first.

You can fix this by rewriting the pthread code like this:

```
iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, producer,(void*) message1);
pthread_join(&thread1, NULL);
iret2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, consumer,(void*) message2);
pthread_join(&thread2, NULL);
```

EDIT: additional note - if you need the threads to be created and run simultaneously, then you can use a mechanism like a semaphore to delay the consumer thread before the producer thread. I don't think that a mutex, while absolutely correct in protecting the sanity of your variables, will still gaurantee the order of thread execution. The only other way is by assigning priorities to the tasks..

Comment: yes im using p_tread join for both the threads after creating a thread

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer to make it a bit clearer..

Comment: if you can explain on mutex and locking variable it will be good for me

Comment: but still, i do get different results for same function in different threads

Comment: what do you get for no_elements() in the first and then second threads ? I would expect 1 and 1.